# One Typescript Function Parameter - Optional Types?

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, function-parameter

I guess I'm bad at looking through documentations, because I can't figure this out:

```
var help = (param: string or number) => {
     return param;
}
```

**How do I allow the `help` function to have a `param` of either a string or number?**

For example:

```
help("string"); //returns "string"

help(123); //returns 123
```

Comment: ```var help = (param: string | number) => {     return param; }```

Comment: wow, I tried double pipes ||, but not just one! I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its just an or `|`

```
var help = (param: string | number) => { return param; }
```